# Sequential Menu (Drill down) or Accordion

Tags: navigation, menu

I have 3 levels in my information architecture for my desktop dashboard. In the vertical navigation which measures H:500px W:200px I have;

- Top level: 8 items
- Second level: 9 items in total (one of my top level item has 7 second levels)
- Third level: 12 items

Would you use an accordion style (which will make the menu long when expanded) or a sequential drill down menu? and why?

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: Sequential drill down menu sound so 1998 to me and has bad usability. Is difficult to navigate between dropdowns, diagonal selection could be a problem. The accordion looks more common for me on side menus. Analyse what is more common for your user and test it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.....it is definitely a matter of testing it with users.

Answer (score 1):

The accordion menu expands its height for navigation through the levels. As your space has more height than width, it may be a good idea to use it, especially if you aim to not expand beyond the designated space. Here is a [good example of a 3 level depth accordion](https://codyhouse.co/demo/multi-level-accordion-menu/index.html#0)

Dropdown menus can have different configurations, however, they always visually expand beyond the first level area. Here is [good coverage of them](https://weblium.com/blog/10-drop-down-and-mega-menu-examples/). You can [google more](https://www.google.com/search?q=examples%20of%20drop%20down%20menus&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB796GB796&sxsrf=ACYBGNTc3P81LJqIVM7u_HePzPRQjB8O1A:1570108253681&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:y&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilv-CFlYDlAhUqShUIHeqnCB8QpwUIKg&biw=1706&bih=802) if you want.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Pavlo

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend an accordion menu.

There are several advantages to this menu style:

- The previous menu items are still visible
- It is flexible, allowing you to have a very long list that is still manageable
- It allows user to jump from the third level back into another top level with a single click
- It is a convention, so many users will be familiar with the UI pattern